# Xcode 7 Swift 2 Memory Leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, xcode7

Totally new at Swift 2.

How can I check for Memory Leaks in my app designed in Swift? I was checking in Google but there are too many documents on it. I'm using Xcode 7, do I have to download any tool to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first two Google hits for "Xcode memory leaks" are ["Memory Usage Performance Guidelines: Finding Memory Leaks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/ManagingMemory/Articles/FindingLeaks.html) and ["Instruments User Guide: Find Memory Leaks"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/FindingLeakedMemory.html) from Apple.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR I'll check them out.

Answer (score 1):

Kindly go through this tool provided by apple.

[Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.

Comment: @Coolboylp Always welcome